# Returning http 400 status code doesnt work

Tags: angular, http

Every internetpage says that this line of code

```
return new ResponseEntity<Customer>(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
```

returns an error code 400, but when i force it i get "405 Method Not Allowed".
Why?

```
@PutMapping(value = "/rest/customer/{id}")
        public Object updateCustomer(@PathVariable(name = "id") long id,
                                     @RequestBody Customer customer) {
        if (id != customer.getId()) {
            return new ResponseEntity<Customer>(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
        } else {
```

Comment: What Framework are you using?

Comment: angular and httprequests with ARC

Comment: what is not allowed is probably calling the page with a GET instead of a POST (the method).  If your fmwk restricts to PUT, you will never execute to the `return` , and the fmwk will exit 405.